# Cache api - add XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage, cacheapi

I have just started using Cache API of javascript. I need to set a header in all my GET request, hence i passed in my request object to the "add" method like the following,

```
        //Request object construction
        let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", reqURL, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('MY-HEADER',myHeaderValue);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); 

        //Cache operations
        let cacheObj = await 
            caches.open(cacheName),
            result = await cacheObj.match(reqURL, options);
        if(emberUtils.isNone(result)) {
            cacheObj.add(xmlHttp);
        } else {
            console.log("match found");
            console.log(result);
        }
```

But instead of the constructed request object, the request is sent with the XMLHttpRequest directly appended to the base url like [www.mytestforcaching.com/[object%20XMLHttpRequest]](http://www.mytestforcaching.com/%5Bobject%20XMLHttpRequest%5D). Please help me with sending the constructed request object or setting headers in the request for cache api.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you use ```xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale");``` for caching http responses? There's no need for a specific function.

Comment: My requirement is to cache the response from server. "Cache-Control" header will just indicate server that it can send stale responses right ? @AbsoluteBeginner